# Flutter Image Picker plugin assigns its own name to each picked file

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm using the image picker plugin for flutter. Whenever I pick an image from the gallery, it is assigned a random name by the plugin, starting with 'image_picker.' How can I get the original name of the image file?

Comment: you cannot - every time a new temporary image is created (at least under android) - https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/a5db6e08042b3f6a44e554fc384c76b9e18c7c62/packages/image_picker/image_picker/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/FileUtils.java#L44

Comment: You can change the file name if you are going to store it in firebase storage. Are you trying to do that?

Comment: Yes @HardikKumar. But the issue is that I want to store the images by their original name.

Comment: did you solve this? I am getting same issue

Comment: No I didn't. You'll have to figure out a workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem with Rest API to which I need to send image files (via Base64) which are name exactly as required by the API. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method as mentioned below. It worked for me

```
var video = (await _picker.getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery))!;

var videoName = video.path.split('/').last;
```